# Select2 reset to placeholder

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I know this is repeated. I searched everywhere and I cannot see where my problem is.

I want to reset the selected value to placeholder.

I have a codepen running in case anyone wants to see the code.

I am using the last version of select2

http://codepen.io/GGarciaSeco/pen/WxNaGo?editors=1111

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".select2").select2({
   placeholder:'A SELECT EXAMPLE',
   width:'100%'
  });

 $("#reset").on('click', function(e){
   console.log('e', e);
   var $select = $("#select")[0];
   console.log($select);
   $($select).select2('val', '');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is causing you the problem here, because it should have just worked fine. But a little trick here could get you what you want. Just set original `select` element's value to `empty` and `trigger` its change `event`.

**Ex:**

```
$("#reset").on('click', function(e){
    $("#select").val('').trigger('change');
});
```

## [`Updated Pen HERE`](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/xOxyXm)

Comment: Anytime... Happy coding.. :) Do upvote and accept the answer if it helped.. :)